# GoDaddy SSL - What's the protocol for CSR files being shared for certificates?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I just got myself a Standard SSL Certificate from GoDaddy then realised I had credit to use on a Premium certificate.

Now, before I make my request for that certificate, I would like to know, what's the deal with the CSR files?

Do I use the same one I used for my standard cert? Should I generate a new one? Does it matter?

Once I have the CRT files, do I keep all my current SSL files? Whice are:

```
[user@host ~]$ ls -l /etc/ssl/localcerts/
total 12
-r-------- 1 root root 1939 Jul 30 12:26 www.website.com.au.crt
-rw-r----- 1 root root 1066 Jul 29 10:13 www.website.com.au.csr
-r-------- 1 root root 1675 Jul 29 10:13 www.website.com.au.key
```

This is the first time I've setup SSL certificates so I have no idea what I'm doing xD

Answer (score 2):

If you will be replacing the Standard certificate with the Premium certificate, you can use the same CSR. If you will be using both of them (for different hostnames for example), you should generate a new CSR and key to increase the security of the key-pair (e.g. if both certificates use the same key and one of them is compromised, then they are both compromised)

Answer (score 1):

Generally.. you use the csr.. then godaddy will send you the crt.. you use the crt with the key to setup ssl

You should save the csr in case you need to re-generate it to save some trouble.

Comment: Yeah, I've done that. But now I want a new, premium, certificate. Do I use the same CSR that I used to setup my first, standard certificate? Or generate a new one? Should a use a new CSR? *can* I use a new CSR?

Comment: use the same one as long as it's still the same hostname for the ssl cert

Answer (score 1):

The CSR has host and organization information along with the public version of your key.  As long as no private key, organization or host information is changing, you can use the same signing request.